# MPMusicPlayerController linker error in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

My media player app was compiling fine and working seamlessly in older versions. 
I upgraded my Xcode and i get the following errors

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libvolumectrl_r.a(PlayerVolumeControl.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried the following based on my previous solutions search

1. Added MediaPlayer.framework in build phase link libraries
2. included following imports in my source files

`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`
`#import <MediaPlayer/MPMusicPlayerController.h>`

i am still unable to compile. Please let me know if there are any other missing steps

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Build Settings -> Valid Architectures -> remove armv7 Architecture.
Only arm64 in Architecture.
Then clean application and build it.No any linker error come.
Please follow this steps.
Regards,
Kinjal

Comment: I cannot compile for arm64, my libraries do not support. I have to build for armv7 and armv7s

Comment: Go to build setting and other linker flag set to -objc. Can you please check this.

Comment: Tried that, it does not help.

Comment: Sorry go to build setting and other linker flag replace -objc to "-ObjC". Can you please check this.Sorry for incorrect flag.